# updating SwiftUI @State variable by value passed in not working? (code attached)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

In the code below after running I see the text in the first row to be "xxxxxxxx" and not "Initial Value we Want".  It appears that the "$strValue.wrappedValue = tempStr" line in the gcRow initialiser is not working?

Question - how to correct so I can correctly pass the initial value for the child view to it, and it uses this correctly?

Playgrounds Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct gcRow : View {
    @State var strValue : String = "xxxxxxxx"
    init(tempStr : String) {
        $strValue.wrappedValue = tempStr  // <== DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
    }
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text(strValue)
        }
    }
}

struct GCParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                gcRow(tempStr: "Initial Value we Want")
            }
        }
    }
}

let gcParentView = GCParentView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: gcParentView)
```

Image/Snapshop of what I see after Startup:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swiftUI its not allowed to change @State variables in the initializer. The correct way is to remove the default value and initialize it inside the initializer.

Fixed Playground Code

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct gcRow : View {
    @State var strValue: String

    init(tempStr: String) {
        _strValue = State(initialValue: tempStr)
    }

    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text(strValue)
        }
    }
}

struct GCParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                gcRow(tempStr: "Initial Value we Want")
            }
        }
    }
}

let gcParentView = GCParentView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: gcParentView)
```

Comment: thanks by the way - wonder what is the principle behind this from a reactive point of view?  i.e. seems you have to effectively "set the state in the init" but not by replacing rather than just setting?

Comment: I Don't actually know the answer to that but the state isn't actually a value but it rather has a wrapped value you can read and write. There is probably some "magic" behind the scenes that does more things when you call the above inside init. When you use @state there are a lot of things swiftUI does for you like when the state changes the view automatically reloads to get ready for the new data....

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this:

```
init(tempStr: String) {
    _strValue = State(initialValue: tempStr)
}
```